# Gwt, How to make Textbox to have more than 1 visible line?

Tags: java, gwt, user-interface, textbox, textarea

In Gwt, the textbox always 1 line which make it difficult for user to see if they type something very long. My question is "How to make Textbox to have more than 1 visible line?" just like TextArea, but unlike TextArea, the user can not make new line in Textbox.

For textArea we got `TextArea txt2=new TextArea();
        txt2.setVisibleLines(2);`
but there no `setVisibleLines` in TextBox

The second solution is to use TextArea & code so that it won't let users to enter a new line. But it don't like to handle Mouse Event like that cos user may copy text from else where & paste them in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see the DOCS of GWT [textbox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextBox.html)

```
 public class TextBox extends TextBoxBase
```

> **A standard single-line text box.**

please go for `textarea`.In that case if your entered more than 1 line split string with `/n` and do your `validation`